# Relay commitUpdate callback with follow-up mutation and missing fragment

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have two GraphQL/Relay mutations that work fine separately. The first one creates an item. The second one runs a procedure for connecting two items.

#### GraphQL

```
createOrganization(
  input: CreateOrganizationInput!
): CreateOrganizationPayload

createOrganizationMember(
  input: CreateOrganizationMemberInput!
): CreateOrganizationMemberPayload

input CreateOrganizationInput {
  clientMutationId: String
  organization: OrganizationInput!
}

input CreateOrganizationMemberInput {
  clientMutationId: String
  organizationMember: OrganizationMemberInput!
}

# Represents a user’s membership in an organization.
input OrganizationMemberInput {
  # The organization which the user is a part of.
  organizationId: Uuid!

  # The user who is a member of the given organization.
  memberId: Uuid!
}

type CreateOrganizationPayload {
  clientMutationId: String

  # The `Organization` that was created by this mutation.
  organization: Organization

  # An edge for our `Organization`. May be used by Relay 1.
  organizationEdge(
    orderBy: OrganizationsOrderBy = PRIMARY_KEY_ASC
  ): OrganizationsEdge

  # Our root query field type. Allows us to run any query from our mutation payload.
  query: Query
}
```

I would like to be able to run the `createOrganization` mutation and then connect the user to the organization with the `createOrganizationMember` mutation. The second mutation takes two arguments, one of which is the newly created edge.

I tried passing the edge into the mutation, but it expects the mutation to be able to `getFragment`. How can I get the fragment for the payload edge so it can be passed into a mutation?

#### React-Relay

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new CreateOrganizationMutation({
        organizationData: data,
        user,
        query,
      }), {
        onSuccess: response => {
          Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
            new CreateOrganizationMemberMutation({
              organization: response.createOrganization.organizationEdge.node,
              user,
            })
          );
        },
      }
    );

  fragments: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        ${CreateOrganizationMutation.getFragment('user')},
        ${CreateOrganizationMemberMutation.getFragment('user')},
      }
    `,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem without changing any GraphQL:

I created a new Relay container, route, and queries object. It is configured as a
child route for the container where the first of two mutation occurs. The `id` for
the new edge is passed as a parameter via the route pathname. A router state
variable is also passed.

#### Routes

```
import {Route} from 'react-router';

function prepareProfileParams (params, {location}) {
  return {
    ...params,
    userId: localStorage.getItem('user_uuid'),
  };
}
    // ProfileContainer has the component CreateOrganizationForm, which calls
    // the createOrganization mutation
    <Route
      path={'profile'}
      component={ProfileContainer}
      queries={ProfileQueries}
      prepareParams={prepareProfileParams}
      onEnter={loginBouncer}
      renderLoading={renderLoading}
    >
      <Route path={'join-organization'}>
        <Route
          path={':organizationId'}
          component={JoinOrganizationContainer}
          queries={JoinOrganizationQueries}
          renderLoading={renderLoading}
        />
      </Route>
    </Route>
```

#### CreateOrganizationForm.js

```
    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new CreateOrganizationMutation({
        organizationData: data,
        user,
        query,
      }), {
        onSuccess: response => {
          const organizationId = response.createOrganization.organizationEdge.node.rowId;
          router.push({
            pathname: `/profile/join-organization/${organizationId}`,
            state: {
              isAdmin: true,
            },
          });
        },
      }
    );
```

The new Relay container `JoinOrganizationContainer` will hook into a lifecycle
method to call the second mutation that we needed. The second mutation has an
`onSuccess` callback which does `router.push` to the page for the new object we
created with the first mutation.

#### JoinOrganizationContainer.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import Relay from 'react-relay';
    import CreateOrganizationMemberMutation from './mutations/CreateOrganizationMemberMutation';

    class JoinOrganizationContainer extends React.Component {
      static propTypes = {
        user: React.PropTypes.object,
        organization: React.PropTypes.object,
      };
      static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object,
        location: React.PropTypes.object,
      };
      componentWillMount () {
        const {user, organization} = this.props;
        const {router, location} = this.context;

        Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
          new CreateOrganizationMemberMutation({
            user,
            organization,
            isAdmin: location.state.isAdmin,
          }), {
            onSuccess: response => {
              router.replace(`/organization/${organization.id}`);
            },
          }
        );
      }
      render () {
        console.log('Joining organization...');
        return null;
      }
    }

    export default Relay.createContainer(JoinOrganizationContainer, {
      initialVariables: {
        userId: null,
        organizationId: null,
      },
      fragments: {
        user: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on User {
            ${CreateOrganizationMemberMutation.getFragment('user')},
          }
        `,
        organization: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on Organization {
            id,
            ${CreateOrganizationMemberMutation.getFragment('organization')},
          }
        `,
      },
    });
```

#### JoinOrganizationQueries.js

```
    import Relay from 'react-relay';

    export default {
      user: () => Relay.QL`
        query { userByRowId(rowId: $userId) }
      `,
      organization: () => Relay.QL`
        query { organizationByRowId(rowId: $organizationId) }
      `,
    };
```

One unexpected benefit of doing things this way is that there is now a shareable url that can be used as an invite link for joining an organization in this app. If the user is logged in and goes to the link: `<host>/profile/join-organization/<organizationRowId>`, the mutation will run that joins the person as a member. In this use case, `router.state.isAdmin` is `false`, so the new membership will be disabled as an admin.